# Как найти дубликаты в векторе датафрейм?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Датафрейм состоит из векторов 'cleanUrl' и 'code_url'
Где 'cleanUrl' ссылка, а 'code_url' ссылка преобразованная в число с помощью:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
```

**Пример файла:**

```
cleanUrl,code_url
amerikan-gruzovik.ru,4590
tinatube.net,74861
sextelevizor.net,66791
ru.anysex.com,62743
www.asiamobil.ru,86865
www.chinamobil.ru,90045
ad-k.ru,2637
www.nik-store.ru,105112
video-seks.net,80108
russkoe-porno.info,63946
www.foxporns.com,94819
www.chrono24.com.ru,90117
www.wibes.ru,118283
german242.com,26297
santdom.ru,65100
treningchess.com,76231
razvedem.web-3.ru,60517
aktis-stroy.ru,3525
www.aktis-stroy.ru,85600
plot.name,56170
www.lichnycabinet.ru,100979
www.worldfishing.narod.ru,118532
sekretka.su,66123
www.a-centre.ru,85011
www.suzukirus.ru,113986
pornogl.com,57123
wmid234ru.ru,83678
hsi.ru,29794
infometer.ru,31244
www.git77.rostrud.ru,95784
www.packagetrackr.com,106632
www.tns-global.ru,115139
www.vipgroup.net,117281
www.toysrus.com,115433
moskva.wisell.ru,46046
www.shopjustice.com,111904
deti75.ru,16625
crimeacity.info,15195
baza.crimea.ua,8838
atelica-oazis.bron.me,6647
gokurort.ru,26990
mitula17.imhonet.ru,44811
foxbrest.imhonet.ru,24645
xavi.imhonet.ru,120090
ural.kp.ru,78539
spb.kp.ru,69996
pinkmarie.com,55650
geneva2015.cars.ru,26188
domodedovo.rujazi.com,18057
xn------5cdjccgu2avckptly3ad8p.xn--e1arcbfn.xn--p1ai,120241
baikalpress.ru,8328
klimovsk.mnogonado.net,35750
svet-modern.ru,72656
www.forex-kf.ru,94627
www.uniq-ip.com,116401
www.terrawoman.ua,114714
www.gorsovet.mk.ua,96192
vmr.gov.ua,81250
helpstu.su,28874
www.helpstu.su,96823
zab-nanny.ru,122892
kursak-diplom.com.ua,37838
kgu-journalist.ucoz.ru,34771
mospf.ru,46093
newdiplom.ucoz.ru,49231
www.autoezda.com,87258
referats.nashisrael.ru,60990
www.hotdiplom.ru,97129
fotorakom.com,24577
redirect.disqus.com,60900
www.sq.com.ua,113207
member.newsnet.in.ua,43580
bankomet.com.ua,8537
po4emu.ru,56252
www.po4emu.ru,107650
tric.info,76258
myotpusk.com,47714
yspehx.narod.ru,122777
vozhatiki.ru,81885
kirent.narod.ru,35483
www.festivalsearcher.com,94080
hotasianz.com.6716069.yupiromo.ru,29549
starblag.ucoz.ua,70955
www.medalbum.ru,102495
ab28ru.narod.ru,2336
diel.ks.ua,16931
aniplay.tv,5091
ugolzreniya.narod.ru,77854
vrn.vestipk.ru,81990
afg-hist.ucoz.ru,3023
www.shanson-plus.ru,111700
www.vsmolenske.ru,117854
vsetutonline.com,82254
stomatologmova.ucoz.ua,71506
xn----8sbgjprccxgonf4d1dya7b.xn--p1ai,120742
yarcube.ru,122335
www.pion.com.ru,107364
76yar.ru,1961
loveplanet-online.ru,40510
```

**Нужно вернуть записи 'code_url', которые совпали с записями 'cleanUrl' в формате датафрейм.**

в полной версии файла 130 тыс. записей. Пробовал вложенным циклом, но процесс встал, очень долго. :

```
d=[]
for a in range(len(df_label_url)):
    for b in range(len(df_label_url)):
        if df_label_url['code_url'][a]==df_label_url['cleanUrl'][b]:
            d.append(df_label_url['code_url'][a])
```

**Предположительно так только в формате датафрейме:**

```
[4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 4590, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 74861, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 66791, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 62743, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 86865, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 90045, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 2637, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 105112, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 80108, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946, 63946]
```

Comment: вы можете привести воспроизводимый пример? какой результат вы хотите получить на выходе для данного примера данных? вы пытаетесь сравнивать URL  с числом? - этот момент я не понял...

Comment: @MaxU Добрый день. Пример результат привести не могу так как на 100 записей возвращается пустой массив D. Я предпологал, что операция сравнения умеет раскодировать число...Варианты раскодировать число обратно в текст, или закодировать столбец cleanUrl

Comment: попробуйте привести небольшой искусственный пример данных (5-10 строк) и результат который хотите получить для данного примера данных. В текущей формулировке непонятно что и с чем вы хотите сравнивать...

Comment: @MaxU добавил как может выглядеть выходной формат.

Comment: вы хотите найти дублирующиеся (если оба поля совпадают) строки?

Comment: @MaxU да, мне нужно вернуть совпадающие строки, если конечно такие в сто записях имеются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти строки, встречающиеся два и более раз можно воспользоваться [DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
                cleanUrl  code_url
0                ad-k.ru      2637
1   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
2           tinatube.net     74861
3   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
4       sextelevizor.net     66791
5          ru.anysex.com     62743
6       sextelevizor.net     66791
7   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
8       sextelevizor.net     66791
9       www.asiamobil.ru     86865
10      sextelevizor.net     66791
11     www.chinamobil.ru     90045
12      sextelevizor.net     66791
13  amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
14               ad-k.ru      2637
```

проверка на дупликаты:

```
In [11]: df.duplicated(keep=False)
Out[11]:
0      True
1      True
2     False
3      True
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10     True
11    False
12     True
13     True
14     True
dtype: bool
```

решение:

```
In [12]: df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[12]:
                cleanUrl  code_url
0                ad-k.ru      2637
1   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
3   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
4       sextelevizor.net     66791
6       sextelevizor.net     66791
7   amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
8       sextelevizor.net     66791
10      sextelevizor.net     66791
12      sextelevizor.net     66791
13  amerikan-gruzovik.ru      4590
14               ad-k.ru      2637
```

PS можно искать дубликаты для выборочных столбцов - для этого надо воспользоваться параметром `subset`:

```
df.duplicated(subset=['cleanUrl'], keep=False)
```

Comment: я неправильно интепретировал задачу.

Comment: скажите пожайлуста, duplicated какой столбец проверяет на дубубликаты ? Я могу начать новую тему и или всё править здесь ?

Comment: @максимильин, по умолчанию все, но можно указать набор столбцов для проверки - параметр: `subset=[...]` Может все-таки попробуете сформулировать вашу задачу так, чтобы было понятно что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @максимильин, лучше наверное новый вопрос - этот вопрос (про поиск дупликатов в dataframe) по-моему еще не задавался - может кому-нибудь пригодится